# SQLite Database only returns first Row in PHP (Even with a Loop!)

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I try to get all of my Data out of a SQLite Database.

This is my Database:

```
ID, Name,      Points
 3, Christian, 50
 1, Jannik,    200
 2, Lena,      50
```

This is the PHP-Code:

```
$res = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM player");
while($row = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

But in the Frontend it echos out only the Row where the ID is equal to 1. In this case the name "Jannik"

Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Are you sure you are querying the _correct_ database / table to begin with?

Comment: Totally stupid mistake. I had to reload the database cache after each change... The code works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No code problem. It was the DB cache

Comment: Delete question